# reboot problem-loosing my software installed

Tags: reboot

I have a strange problem don't know the exact problem. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Oracle Virtual-box in Windows 10 system and i'm trying to install Caffe on Ubuntu after the installation is done the test programs runs fine but once the system is shut down and restarted all my installation is gone for a toss.

I will not be able to invoke Caffe software again nor my my other software installation packages but the folders are retained in the system.
Could anyone please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you _installed_ Ubuntu? Isn’t it a live session with a persistent storage?

Answer (score 0):

Installed Ubuntu or just used as live mode??

I don't know the permanent solution.

Temporary solution i.e. do not restart VirtualBox Ubuntu OS, just save machine state.

[image]